# Laravel 8/9 factories in a package not resolving properly

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on developing a Laravel 9 package and I cannot get the factories to resolve properly. In my package's composer file, I have the following:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Zam\\Authentication\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Zam\\Authentication\\": "src/"
    }
  },
```

Here's my model for managing user phone numbers:

```
<?php

namespace Zam\Authentication\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserPhone extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'phone', 'type', 'primary', 'verified',
    ];

    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return \Zam\Authentication\Factories\UserPhoneFactory::new();
    }
}
```

And here's my factory for that model

```
<?php namespace Zam\Authentication\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Zam\Authentication\Models\UserPhone;

class UserPhoneFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = UserPhone::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'type' => 'personal',
            'primary' => $this->faker->boolean(),
            'verified' => $this->faker->boolean(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Inside of my main project, I have a seeder that is attempting to call the package's phone number factory like this:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Zam\Authentication\Models\UserPhone;

class SiteUserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        User::factory()->count(10)->create()->each(function($user) {
            $user->phoneNumbers()->save(UserPhone::factory()->create());
        });
    }
}
```

This throws the following error. I cannot figure out why the file path will not resolve properly. I have no issues accessing all the different classes within my package's `src` directory, but when trying to access the `database/factories` directory, nothing will resolve. All the auto-completion shows up properly and the file is properly resolved in my package, just won't work from my core project.

```
Class "Zam\Authentication\Factories\UserPhoneFactory" not found
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured it out. Was missing the classmap in my core project's composer.

```
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/BrowserKitTestCase.php",
            "vendor/zam/auth/database/factories" // This was needed
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

Comment: It is not recommended to do what you did, a `factory` is part of the `dev` of THAT package, it should not be shared with anything else, but do what you would like to do